# what is raw pointer in c++? How they differ from normal pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there is any special meaning for raw pointer?

Is normal pointer variable and raw pointer are same?

Comment: [Google your title](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=raw+pointer+c%2B%2B&oq=raw+pointer+c%2B%2B&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i61.1942j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: which eventually points back to StackOverflow: [Pointers, smart pointers or shared pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417481/pointers-smart-pointers-or-shared-pointers) and `Raw Pointers` == `Normal Pointers`

Comment: This post might answer your question: [Pointers, smart pointers or shared pointers?][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417481/pointers-smart-pointers-or-shared-pointers

Comment: duplicate comments???above ^ :-)

Comment: The link isn't an answer at all.  He's looking for a definition of raw pointer, not a discussion of pointers which assumes the reader understands the jargon beforehand.

Answer (score 10):

The raw pointers are exactly the same with normal pointers, they can be written like this:

```
type * pointer_name = & variable_name;
```

Since C++11, we have some special pointers, called "smart pointers". They are called "smart" because they know when they have to delete the used memory. They do it when nothing else in your program uses that block of memory. There are 3 types of smart pointers in C++11:

```
unique_ptr<typename> pointer_name;
weak_ptr<typename> pointer_name;
shared_ptr<typename> pointer_name;
```

You can read more about using these types of pointers [here](http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/C++11_smart_ptrs.pdf).

Comment: `smart_ptr`? Never heard of it. What about `unique_ptr`?

Comment: sorry @Thanatos, thanks for your comment. I was thinking of something else and that was the result. :))

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a raw pointer is a normal pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Depend on what you are qualifying a "normal" pointer, a raw pointer is written like this:

```
int* rawptr;
```

With c++11, I would suggest to avoid it whenever its possible. Use std::unique_ptr instead.

Comment: And what about std::unique_ptr::get? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719119/bad-practice-to-return-unique-ptr-for-raw-pointer-like-ownership-semantics and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when