# Returning unique_ptr in Factory

Tags: c++, factory-pattern, unique-ptr

Maybe this is a simple question, because I'm still new to C++. I would like to use some kind of factory to encapsulate the logging in my application. The idea is that only the factory knews which concrete class will handle the function calls. The application will always call abstract interfaces of the base logging class.

The factory method should look like:

```
std::unique_ptr<AbstractLoggingClass> Factory::getDefaultLogger(const std::string& param){
    return new ConcreteLoggingClass(param);
}
```

`ConcreteLoggingClass` is a subclass of `AbstractLoggingClass`.

But I get the following error:

```
Error: could not convert '(operator new(64ul), (<statement>,
((ConcreteLoggingClass*)<anonymous>)))' from 'ConcreteLoggingClass*'
to 'std::unique_ptr<AbstractLoggingClass>'
```

My problem is that I don't know how to instantiate `ConcreteLoggingClass` and return a `unique_ptr` to `AbstractLoggingClass`

I already found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719119/bad-practice-to-return-unique-ptr-for-raw-pointer-like-ownership-semantics), but I still don't see the solution.

Comment: Why? Could you please explain instead of just silently downvote.

Comment: I still don't get the downvote. But thanks to everybody else for the useful answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `std::unique_ptr` constructor you want is [`explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean), hence you need to be... well... explicit about it. Try

```
return std::unique_ptr<AbstractLoggingClass>(new ConcreteLoggingClass(param));
```

Comment: That did the job. Thank you very much!

Comment: Correct answer as far C++ goes, but I don't know why C++ made this decision. A `ConcreteLoggingClass` is a `AbstractLoggingClass` using the "is a"  in  the sense of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Answer (score 13):

If you can use C++14 you should use `std::make_unique`:

```
return std::make_unique<ConcreteLoggingClass>( param );
```

otherwise explicitly create `std::unique_ptr`:

```
return std::unique_ptr<AbstractLoggingClass>{ new ConcreteLoggingClass{param}};
```

Comment: I dont have C++14 yet. But I already knew about make_unique. This looks very handy.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `std::unique_ptr<T>` is `explicit`. It won't implicitly convert from a pointer as doing so would mean a pointer is silently deleted.

You can return a `std::unique_ptr<T>` explicitly constructing it, e.g.:

```
return std::unique_ptr<AbstractLoggingClass>(new ConcreteLoggingClass(param));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert your pointer to a `unique_ptr`, you have to create it :

```
std::unique_ptr<AbstractLoggingClass> Factory::getDefaultLogger(const std::string& param){
    return std::unique_ptr<AbstractLoggingClass>(new ConcreteLoggingClass(param));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have c++14 or better:

```
std::unique_ptr<AbstractLoggingClass> 
Factory::getDefaultLogger(const std::string& param)
{
    return std::make_unique<ConcreteLoggingClass>(param);
}
```

Comment: I have no c++14 available at the moment. But thank you for making this suggestion, maybe I can use this in the future.